# How to keep files "reusable" in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, git

This might be simple but all I want is for it to be possible for files that contain Swift extensions to be reusable in other projects. For example, I have an extension of `Date` in Date.swift and want that if I change it in one project to add more code, the other projects that use it will get these changes too. I've tried just dragging these docs in a file as reference to that file on my computer (it uses git too) but when I used git and collaborated with a friend on GitHub in the nesting project it started making problems. Is this the best way though?

Comment: Using CocoaPods seems like a logical path perhaps...

Comment: Don't do that. Very very bad practice that could break several projects! If you need to reuse a file, just copy it.

Comment: @ThiagoAM: That's the whole issue the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Also, CocoaPods is a dependency manager, and pretty much entire point of using it.

Comment: You might want to consider Git Submodules